# display images whose url in the database

Tags: php, html, laravel

In my laravel project .. the images don't display when i fetch their urls from the database ! the url is correct in the Html code .. when i copy it from the page source then open it in a new tab .. the images load .. then if i go back to my website and refresh .. the image load normally .. without any change in the html .. if i close the website and reopen it .. it doesn't load !

here's the code

```
<img src="{{$show->poster}}" title="{{$show->title}}" alt="{{$show->title}}" width="70" height="100">
```

and here's the generated code from the page source

```
<img src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjI1Mzc4MDUwNl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDAzOTIxMjE@._V1_SX300.jpg" title="The Big Bang Theory" alt="The Big Bang Theory" width="70" height="100">
```

Comment: Does dev tools give you any indication of whats wrong? Open up dev tools, switch to the network tab (for chrome) and then refresh the page. Look for the image in the list of objects and check the response.

Comment: GET http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTk4MzM0MTU2MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMTIwMzg3MjE@._V1_SX300.jpg 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: "__Referral Denied__"

Comment: Does that image exist? If you go to the one in your code above (http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjI1Mzc4MDUwNl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDAzOTIxMjE@._V1_SX300.jpg) works fine if you manually browse to it. But the one you just linked in comments doesn't, that suggests a broken link.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IMDB Poster URL Returns Referral Denied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11044010/imdb-poster-url-returns-referral-denied)

Comment: ok .. sorry for asking the same question .. i thought it's something with my code .. not the imdb api itself .. thank you